# EUC-KR encoded XML Shows as invalid Korean character

Tags: node.js, express, decode, cjk

We are fetching a EUC-KR encoded XML data `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='EUC-KR' ?>` , while printing the value in console or saving the data in file show as `<![CDATA[����Ư���� ������ �������87�� 29 (�Ｚ��, M TOWER) 6��]]>` from one of the node value,

So I used 'icon-lite' package to translate the data but this prints in invalid korean character `![CDATA[羲羲�羲羲 羲羲羲 羲羲羲�87羲 29 (�:羲, M TOWER) 6羲]]`,

I'm using nodejs and express.js to fetch this data from external server, I just wanted the file to be saved or processed to JSON in Korean language without any changes.

reaching out here so that someone can help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: `const { decode } = require('iconv-lite'); decode(euckrBuf, 'euc-kr')` does the job for me. Can you show us the code?

Comment: ```axios.get(`${URL}`, config).then(result => {
    let str;
    let xml = res.data;
    console.log(result.data);
    let content = result.data;  
   var utf8Text = iconv.decode(content, "EUC-KR"); 
    console.log(utf8Text);

})```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you might've been trying to convert from invalid UTF-8 string to UTF-8.

Add `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` to `config` will show valid Korean.

```js
axios.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
.then(response => {
  console.log(decode(response.data, 'euc-kr'));
});
```